# loop through json array having complex variable

Tags: angularjs, json, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to loop through json array inside the template, here is what I have tried:

Json array is in this format:  `[{"a":123,"b":234},{"a":1233,"b":23232}]`

when I give this expression:

```
<div ng-repeat=(name,value) in row.entity["'+branch_name+'_wu_tester_detail"]>{{name}} :: {{value}} </div>
```

I m getting this error:

> Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] Expected expression in form of 'item in
>   _collection[ track by _id]' but got '(name,value)'.

Also I have tried this:

```
<div ng-repeat=items in row.entity["'+branch_name+'_wu_tester_detail"]>{{items.tester_id}} :: {{items.workunit_id}}</div>
```

But this also is not working.

FYI here the `branch_name` is variable and the value of `row.entity["'+branch_name+'_wu_tester_detail"]` is in format of `[{"a":123,"b":234},{"a":1233,"b":23232}]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: JFYI..  if anyone have confusion about the inverted commas after ng-repeat. this works completely fine:  <div class="" ng-if=row.entity[\"'+branch_name+'_details\"]!=\"NotEnabled\">

Comment: You might give it a try as below
<div ng-repeat="(name,value) in row.entity[''+branch_name+'_wu_tester_detail']">{{name}} :: {{value}} </div>

Comment: btw, what was an error in this case `<div ng-repeat=items in row.entity....`

Comment: Getting this error in tht case.. Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got 'items'.

Comment: Filter out the data using function in controller

Comment: its simple ng-repeat.. of json array.. for this writing filter is good idea? If it is not possible this way.. then will see..

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find any perfect solution but got a good workaround. Here it seems angular is confused while parsing the expression in ng-repeat. Even escape character doesn't seems to work. So I stored this variable to a much simpler otehr variable using ng-init and then I used ng-repeat, which solved the problem.

If there are any better way, please add to this question, I will add that as accepted answer.

```
<div ng-init=myJsonVar=row.entity[\"'+branch_name+'_wu_tester_detail\"]> {{myJsonVar}}</div><div ng-repeat="item in myJsonVar">IN{{item.tester_id}} :: {{item.workunit_id}} </div>
```